# Form Registration with PHP

Tags: php, session, registration

Please help me out with this registration form. It's evident to me that my there are a couple of errors in my PHP script. My HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="script_1.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

and my php script looks like:

```
<?php

    // Initialize session data
    session_start();

    /*
     * If the user is already registered, display a 
     * message letting them know.
     */

     if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
         echo "You're already registered as" .$_SESSION[username];  // Corrected on Stack Overflow
     }

     // Checks if the form was submitted 
     else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
         /*
          * If both the username and email fields were filled 
          * out, save the username in a session variable and 
          * output a thank you message to the browser. To
          * eliminate leading and trailing whitespace, we use
          * trim() function.
          */

          $uname = isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';   // Corrected on Stack Overflow
          $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';         // Corrected on Stack Overflow

          if(!empty($uname) && !empty($email)) {        // Corrected on Stack Overflow

              $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;

              echo "Thanks for registering! <br />",
              "Username: $uname <br />",
              "Email: $email <br />";
          }

          /*
           * If the user did not fill out both fields, display
           * a message letting them know that both fields are 
           * required for registration.
           */
           else {
               echo "Please fill out both fields! <br />";
           }
     }

     // If the form was not submitted, displays the HTML form
     else {

?>

<?php } ?>
```

I need it to check if the input fields contain something and then perform an action. I also need it to perform a different function if nothing is inserted in these fields.

Comment: Your form field `name` doesn't match your PHP which is looking for `username`.

Comment: Oh my word... Sorry man. I had spent like 8 hours learning PHP and I'm dead right now, but mostly, thanks for everything. You have saved me...

Answer (score 0):

In your form script you have the input name as name

Either change this to

or change your script_1.php change all

$_POST['username']

to

$_POST['name']

Answer (score 0):

In your form script you have the input name as name

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Either change this to

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

or change your script_1.php change all

```
$_POST['username']
```

to

```
$_POST['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `FORM` you use `<input type="text" name="name" />` so you shoulduse
 `$_POST['name'] instead` of `$_POST['username']` because `$_POST['username']` doesn't exist at all. You don't have `textbox` named `username`.

```
 echo "Thanks for registering! <br />",
              "Username: $uname <br />",
              "Email: $email <br />";
```

And if you echoing the variable in php you should do this in this way:

```
echo "Thanks for registering! <br />",
echo "Username: ". $uname."<br />";
echo "Email: ". $email."<br />";
```